# Customising UIPopover appearance

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller

I'd like to change the corner radius and arrow shape (more pointed that curved like in iOS 7). Is this possible?

Comment: [UIPopoverBackgroundView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverBackgroundView_class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Thanks man! This set me on the right track!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the way I solved this was to create a custom popover image using [GIKPopoverBackgroundView](https://github.com/GiK/GIKPopoverBackgroundView). It's a really nice drop in class that takes care of the image stretching etc for you. I just edited the supplied PSD and went from there.